# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application while importing textgenrrn

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to launch a *textgenrnn* neural network on my PC. I used a python program that previously was launched successfully on my laptop. Executing a line in a script `from textgenrnn import textgenrnn`
renders the following error message.

```
F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/Programming/neuralnet/main.py
2020-09-26 22:32:15.280632: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-09-26 22:32:15.280632: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming/neuralnet/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from text_train import train, generate
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\text_train.py", line 1, in <module>
    from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\textgenrnn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .textgenrnn import textgenrnn
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\textgenrnn\textgenrnn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler, Callback
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 56, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse as scipy_sparse  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "E:\Utility\Python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

As you can see, the network initializes, but then the system throws this error.
I use pycharm, Python 3.7, Windows 7 64 bit. While handling previous problems that appeared when I was trying to launch *textgenrr*, I reinstalled Python **to a 64-bit version**. I also tried reistalling NumPy, Keras and Textgenrnn later, but it had no effect on this very program. I tried both installing NumPy via pip, via Pycharm GUI and manually via the wheels from `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy`, since I had a suspicion that the NumPy is incompatible. Now I have an official NumPy module installed, it is an amd-64 version.

Python is installed in `E:\Utility\Python` directory, and the progrm is launched from `F:\Programming\neuralnet\venv\`

Does anyone has an idea, what may be the reason of my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix this - `Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'`, by installing cuda ?

Comment: @Prabindh
No, I did not. As far as I understand, tensorflow is compatible with only NVIDIA GPUs, while I have an AMD one. Thus, I thought that tensorflow will run through CPU and ignored this warning.

Anyway, shall I install cuda simply via pip?

Comment: You need Nvidia GPU for CUDA.

Comment: @Prabindh Yes, that's why I use cpu both on my laptop and on my desktop. However, the laptop worked fine, but the desktop threw this